# Browser for Android in application

Tags: android

I want to create a mini-browser for existing site.
 I use the following code:

```
 WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);
    webview.loadUrl("http://my_url");
```

Wed page opened in application, but next web-links open in standart Android browser.
How to make sure that the web-pages open within the application, not Android browser?

Comment: [Nice Tutorial for your question.](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/58.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use This In Your Code..

```
WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

That should do it, so now all clicked links open in your browser

Answer (score 0):

Maybee you could set an intentfilter for your activity like this

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
     <data android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```

So any time a link is opened you are asked to use your app as browser.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: The correct way to go about this is the method i have provided above. =) Good thinking though.